# "php artisan migrate" on CircleCI results in "could not find driver"

Tags: laravel, circleci

I would like to run my Laravel Project on Circle CI. But I encounter this error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 664:

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t  
  able_schema = test_db and table_name = migrations)                           


In Connector.php line 67:

  could not find driver  


Exited with code 1
```

Comment: using docker or?

Comment: You have also to install php-mysql extention in docker for circle CI

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Comment: We would need to see what executor you are running and how you have configured your build environment. This is all contained in your `.circleci/config.yml`. Would you add that to your question please, using the formatting/editing tools provided?